# filter a servlet at method level

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, servlet-filters

Is there a way to apply a filter to a servlet at method level? I don't want every method of the servlet to be filtered.

Maybe I should not use filters, I am not a java expert. I want to validate the FaceBook cookie in some methods of my GWT server code, but not all.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with a simple `Filter` mapping. It's however possible with a [Java EE container managed security](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkbaa.html) mapping ([example here](http://www.jspwiki.org/wiki/ContainerManagedSecurity)). So if this filter is intented to do authorization checks, then you might want to consider using container managed security instead. Otherwise you've to cast the `ServletRequest` back to [`HttpServletRequest`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) and then determine the value of its [`getMethod()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getMethod%28%29) in the filter.